# Skip processing individual triangles or vertices of the mesh

Tags: xna, monogame, hlsl

In my game I have a billiard table, and a floor below the table. In typical situation the table covers 80% of the screen, so only small amount of the floor is visible. And I render the table first, so invisible part of the floor is discarded by the depth buffer test.

But profiling with Nsight shows me drawing the floor takes significant amount of time, and it is spent in the rasterizer. It seems generating all those pixels of the floor and depth testing them takes a long time.

I'm wondering how to solve this problem and one thing I tried is to divide the floor (a rectangle with two triangles) to multiple rectangles, so some of them could be cancelled in an earlier stage. The problem is, this is still one model / mesh, just with more triangles and I don't know how to start.

What would be a way to achieve this in Monogame + HLSL? Somewhere in vertex shader? Or gemoetry shader (is it supported in monogame?)

Or is there any other way to optimize this?

UPDATE: the whole floor is needed and might be drawn depending on where the camera is, so I can't get rid of parts of it. In typical situations table top covers 80% of the screen because of perspective and looking down at an angle. The game is in 3D.

Comment: Consider breaking the table into sections and render only what is in the Frustum.

Answer (score 2):

Break the floor geometry such that invisible pieces are not there at all

Comment: How do I achieve this? Update: whole floor is needed sometimes, will update the question.

Comment: Use blender or any 3d program to edit the model

Comment: I think you mean removing the floor which is always not visible - this is not possible. I updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: Then I think...ordering the objects is thy only way

Comment: Or make the floor into 2 objects...one always visible..like a frame .and Inge hardly visible.Both of which you tried

Comment: Imagine looking at the middle of the billiard table while standing in some distance next to it. Sometimes the "frame of the floor" which is around the table will be the only thing that actually gets to the camera view, especially with low FOV. Yet 80% of it (sometimes 100) is covered by the table.

Comment: Based on camera position modify the draw call for floor...

Comment: This is what I want to do, but for this I need to divide the floor into many smaller shapes, which I can then decide not to draw. Hence the question. The number of those shapes easily reaches hundreds (squares or triangles) and I don't want them to be separate shapes / meshes to not have problem with too many draw calls, not to mention maintaining this model.

Answer (score 1):

You have these options:

- Render the table first, and the floor second and have depth testing on. This will cancel calling the pixel shader on the floor pixels where the table has already been drawn. (though the rasterizer will still do its work) (edit: Oh I see you are already doing that)
- Frustum culling: don't render anything that is not in the view frustum. Usually visibility is determined by checking the object's bounding box against the view frustum.
- Occlusion culling: Don't call the draw if it is occluded. I don't know if occlusion queries are available i XNA though. It is also doable by a software occlusion culling technique, but I doubt it would be fast enough if it is done in C#. This is a broad topic, I won't get into details here.
- Culling primitives in the geometry shader. This is not available in XNA, but in monogame it is when using a DirectX 11 renderer. For each primitive you can test it against the view frustum, and decide if you want to send it to the pixel shader. I don't know if adding this extra shader stage will help you or not though, it's just an idea.

Comment: Frustrum culling and occlusion culling - if I understand correct - would be options to get rid of the whole object, not individual parts of it. And while I'm fine with splitting the floor to multiple triangles, I think it doesn't make sense to make it multiple objects and render in several batches - or does it?

Comment: The last option is interesting, but I thought Geometry Shading is not available in monogame. Can you point me into right direction?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but Monogame has a DX11 backend and that could be capable of running a geometry shader. Splitting big objects into smaller ones might help, if you use a CPU side culling technique, think about splitting a huge terrain into chunks, because you wouldn't want to render a million vertices.

Comment: It seems Monogame doesn't support GS. It is on the wish list but implementation is probably complicated..